# display 2 tables on link by id

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a table with id, name, address, sector, financiar, link
on the link i when i press it i want to show me 2 tables from the id of row selected, ex: id 1.
http://postimg.org/image/khelg1m0z/

and the result: http://s28.postimg.org/srvcwj065/Capture2.jpg

now it's a static page with search clause where by id 1, but i need an automatically link show by id on each row.

```html
<?php
include "connect.php";
$sql = "select * from studenti where id='1'";


$query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

?>

<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">
<tr><td>Id</td>
<td>Nume</td>
<td>Localitate</td>
<td>Judet</td>
<td>Sector Financiar</td>
<td>Link</td></tr>

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['nume']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['localitate']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['judet']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['sector_financiar']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['link']; ?></td>



<?php } ?>
</table>

<?php
include "connect.php";
$sql1 = "select * from certificari where id='1' ";


$query = mysql_query($sql1) or die (mysql_error());

?>

<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">
<tr><td>Id</td>
<td>Denumire certificare</td>
<td>Serie si numar certificare</td>
<td>Data certificarii</td>
<td>Valabilitate certificare</td>
<td>Sector Financiar</td></tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['nume']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['serie_numar']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['data']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['valabilitate']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['sector_financiar']; ?></td>


<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you say what you need exactly? You need to display all the records with 1,2,3, ... as their id in the view table and the link with that id?

Comment: when i press the link, i want to show me in another page all the records for id 1, if the link is at the first row, and all records for id 2, if is row 2 with id 2., and so on.
in other words Displaying individual records

Comment: when the results are displayed, I want the user to be able to click on link and then for a new page to display information from my database regarding this particular record. i hope now it's a bit cleared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the `mysql_` functions since they are depricated and are very vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html). Instead, I will use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) in this answer, but you could also use PDO if you want to.

To display records for different ID's based on what the user selects you can pass an ID in the page URL. When you link to the page you add the desired ID to the address like this:

```
<a href="page.php?id=4">Link</a>
```

The value of the variable `id` will now be available in `page.php` as `$_GET['id']`.

The actual PHP in your page would then look something like the code below. I have left out some of your HTML for brevity, but you can just add it int.

```
//Connect to the DB. Might want to put this in your connect.php and include it.
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

//Prepare the statement. The ? will be your ID.
$statment = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM studenti WHERE id = ?");

//Bind the parameters, so that the first (and only) question mark is turned into your ID.
//The 'i' means integer, if you store the id as a string your should use 's' instead.
$statement->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);

//Execute the query.
$statement->execute();

//Get the results.
$result = $statement->get_result();

//Iterate over it to create the output.
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>
    <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['nume']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['localitate']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['judet']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['sector_financiar']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['link']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?

}

//Then do the same thing for the table certificari.
//Note that you only need to connect to the DB once.
```

This [beginners guide](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) to MySQLi is very helpful if you need some more guidance.